# Apache service refuse to start on wamp 2.5

Tags: php, mysql, apache, joomla, wamp

This is my issue and it has given me sleepless night.
I have been working on the wamp 2.1 server environment for the past 3 years and now i want to upgrade. I finally installed wamp 2.5 and would be willing to keep my previous wamp 2.1 version. everything looks good, because after installation, i did the following after:

```
Copied ?:\wamp_old\bin\apache to ?:\wamp\bin
Copied ?:\wamp_old\bin\mysql to ?:\wamp\bin
Copied ?:\wamp_old\bin\php to ?:\wamp\bin
```

Now, the issue is this: 
Whenever i start the wamp server with the latest version, it works and the icon turns green. but whenever i try changing/switching back to the old version, all the services starts except the Apache. the icon stays orange and never turns green. whenever i click test port, it tells me your port 80 is not actually used. when i click on install service, i get this message: your port 80 is available, install will proceed. when i select remove service, it removes immediately. when i click start/resume service, nothing happens and it never starts.

What I want to achieve is this: 
Some old joomla site were developed on the former wamp 2.1 and each time i tried accessing them via the new wamp 2.5, i see some deprecated functions and it display some chunks of codes. meanwhile, i have two projects that refuse to run on the old wamp 2.1, so i decided to run the 2.5. Presently,  the system has wamp 2.5 running.

For 5 days now, i have been cracking my head and i have been stucked.. someone out there should please help me with a solution to run wamp 2.1 and wamp 2.5 together so i can switch version easily.  or a probably solution will be appreciated.

Kind Regards !

Comment: Are you trying while the new one is running? I could not get that.

Comment: If i may get you right, yes, the latest version works fine and no itches, just that old joomla sites bring alot of deprecated errors when i use the latest version. but i would like to switch version between the old and new..any idea?

Comment: I meant, are you stopping the new one before starting the old one? If not, then you should use any other port than 80.

Comment: yes, i stopped the new one before starting the old one.. also, i have changed port or is there any other way to change port.?

Comment: Can you add the error message at the end of your question?

Comment: which of the error message? i dont seem to get any error message. can you elaborate more please?

Comment: these are part of the error:


[Sun Jul 06 17:41:30.545226 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7016:tid 304] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun Jul 06 17:45:04.503464 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1540:tid 372] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sun Jul 06 17:45:06.507578 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7016:tid 304] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sun Jul 06 17:45:06.985606 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1540:tid 372] AH00430: Parent: Child process 7016 exited successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track copying the old Apache MySQL and PHP folders into the new 2.5 version.

Unfortunately switching to very old versions from the new ones is now a bit more hassle than it used to be because of the changes made in the version of compiler used to compile Apache and PHP.

Your old versions of Apache and PHP were compiled with MSVC6 and the new versions with MSVC11 and the 2 are not compatible i.e. an Apache compiled with VC11 wont run with a PHP compiled with VC6 etc.

So try this :-

Switch from Apache 2.4.9 to your old version, it wont start because the PHP version will still be 5.5.12. 
Ignore the problem.

Now switch to an old version of PHP, thats compatible with the old Apache.

With luck it will now work.
Check you have the correct version by looking at phpinfo

If it does not come up re-do the switch to the old apache and then again to the old PHP by just re-clicking the version numbers on the relevant switch menu.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't know if it would be possible to restore everything to work fine. I had once similar problems - I had Wampserver and installed new PHP version for WAMP and switched to new PHP version and eveything stopped to work. I tried to change PHP version to the previous one but I had info it's not compatible with Apache and I couldn't change PHP version because of chosen PHP version.

Now I moved to easyPHP and it's much more easier, you can have many PHP versions, there's no problem with changing them.

Probably in your case the problem was not WAMP itself but PHP versions. That's why when you launched your older code you have many warnings. You should simple select older PHP version to do that or you simple have to turn off warning (maybe for other PHP version you had turned off displaying warnings by default?).

If I were you, I would move to easyPHP, dump your databases (if any) and move everything to easyPHP. Probably you won't make your installation of WAMPserver work so the other option is backup everything, dump your databases and reinstall WAMPserver but you can be almost sure similar problem occurs sooner or later when you will be switching between PHP versions.

Comment: i dont really get what you mean. i developed sites using Joomla and drupal. I have 2 latest clients jobs and the templates required a higher version of php, thats why i installed 2.5, now, because of the 2 latest jobs, i cant access over 30 sites which was developed with wamp 2.1. please, is it possible to run two instances of wamp on a PC, your advise will be appreciated !

Comment: No, you cannot run 2 instances of WAMP. You can try reinstall it as I said (but make sure you create backups) or move to another server as for example `http://www.easyphp.org/` and configure PHP version you used in earlier projects

Comment: hi Marcin, can we please take the response away from here. my email is dolpaz11@gmail.com. but when you say "reinstall" do you mean i should make do with 2.5 and re-install 2.1? hoping to read from you soonest !

Comment: Hi @Marcin, so if i may get you right, i should just re-install the wamp 2.1 right??

Comment: @user3749544 It depends what is your projects needs. If they use PHP that could be installed to Wamp 2.5 you can use Wampserver 2.5 but I don't know anything more about your projects

Comment: Ouch !, am doomed..so i will have to make do with one..either i install the old wamp and let my old site be, or i install wamp 2.5 and work on the new project. so no other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

After alot of brainstorming, I finally resolved the issue all by myself.
Though it may not look wise, but i believe it could go a long way to help others who are stucked in situations like this.

First, I started the wamp 2.5, changed all the versions to the latest ones, which is Apache, Mysql and Php... when the icon turned green, I decided to stop all services, uninstalled the services one after the other. (Apache and mysql) and exit the application by right clicking.

Secondly, I renamed the wamp which encapsulates the 2.5 version to wamp_2.5old and renamed the 2.1 folder back to wamp. i launched the wamp and installed the services back again..this time, it was a lower version. both php and apache had just one version while my sql had two. I made sure the right version of sql was selected and i installed it. I restarted all the services, the icon turned green and all my old website worked.

I tried the method vice-versa and all my latest projects worked. it might look challenging but thats my own way of discovering running multiple version of wamp.

Lastly, thanks to  Özgür Eroğlu and  Marcin Nabiałek.. they have been of helped.

Pleas help me flag this as useful for research..

vielen gluck.. good luck guys !